# Exporting BSplineFunction to Excel

Tags: export, excel, splines

I am trying to export the data from a B Spline Function to a table in excel.  I have tried exporting as many different file types `(.xls, .txt, .dat)`, but all of them show up in excel as all of the data in one cell.

Currently, all I have successfully done is this, showing a plot of "data1", a set of ordered pairs that I imported, and the B-spline fit for this data set.

```
f = BSplineFunction[data1]
Show[
 ListLinePlot[data1, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}]]
```

I would like to export the data from the B-spline function in a way that can be viewed as a table in *Excel*.

Comment: Can you give us some idea of what data1 looks like?

Comment: data1 is a set of about 500 of these ordered pairs, with the x-coordinate ranging from 0.3 to 12, in varying step sizes: {0.3, 0.0558}, {0.302, 0.0556}, {0.304, 0.0554}, {0.306, 0.0552}, {0.308, 0.0552}, {0.31, 0.055}, {0.312, 0.0548}, {0.314, 0.0546}, {0.316, 0.0544},...

Comment: Now I don't understand: what do you mean the "data" from the Bspline... this is an interpolating function, it is not data. Do you want values of the f (the B-spline function) at certain points?

Comment: Yes. sorry about that. I am looking for the values of f

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to map your function over a suitable list of points which fit the needs of the values  you require.

```
RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {20,2}];

f = BSplineFunction[%]

Export["myfile.tsv",f[#]&/@ Range[0, 1, 0.1]]
```

> {{31., 76.}, {52.4823, 17.653}, {29.8387, 21.6133}, {47.3833, 
>     64.0472}, {39.5027, 23.1}, {53.2083, 46.5833}, {58.128, 
>     67.6787}, {62.9102, 39.1387}, {39.7933, 19.064}, {90.7272, 
>     26.2918}, {21., 66.}}